# htmlspecialchars returning normal html

Tags: php

I'm sending a post request to a URL using curl and when I try and remove the html chars it just continues to display the formatted html on my webpage, ideally I don't want it to display anything but making it display unformatted html is better than formatted html, Any ideas as to where im going wrong ?

```
<?php
$url = 'https://example.com/';
$fields = array(
'postParam' => 'xxxxxx'
);

foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
rtrim($fields_string, '&');

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

$result = htmlspecialchars(curl_exec($ch));
curl_close($ch);

//do something with the result

?>
```

Comment: You want `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);`

Comment: thanks, cant believe I didn't spot that >_>